# Create view and replace null values with a word

Tags: mysql, string, view, replace, null

I have a view and I want to change the nulls in a column with a word: `other`.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
CREATE VIEW APB1 AS
  SELECT jos_jam.postcode, location_id, description, 
         category, apb.street, location, apb
  FROM jos_jam
  LEFT JOIN apb
  ON jos_jam.postcode=apb.postcode;
  FROM apb
  UPDATE APB1 SET apb = 'Other' where apb is null
```

That did not replace the values correctly, I also tried:

```
CREATE VIEW APB1 AS
  SELECT jos_jam.postcode, location_id, description, 
         category, apb.street, location, apb
  FROM jos_jam
  LEFT JOIN apb
  ON jos_jam.postcode=apb.postcode;
  REPLACE(apb.apb, 'NULL') as 'Other'
  FROM apb
```

I get the following error for the second query:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'FROM apb
UPDATE APBVolunteers4 SET apb = 'Other' where apb is null' at line 1
```

What does this error mean and how do I replace null values with a word in a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message refers to the semicolon before the word FROM in the first query or the word Replace in the second query.

You cannot put an update statement inside of a create view statement. That looks like you were attempting to update the database rather than update what gets returned in the view.

Also you don't need a From APB at the bottom of your statement.

The COALESCE() operator returns the first not-null value in its list of arguments.

I think this should work:

```
CREATE VIEW APB1 AS
    SELECT jos_jam.postcode, location_id, description, category, apb.street, 
    location, COALESCE(apb, 'Other') as apb
FROM jos_jam
LEFT JOIN apb
   ON jos_jam.postcode=apb.postcode
```